# Accountant has not filed my business taxes

Tags: taxes

Today is January 23, 2020. I still have not received my tax returns on my business for the tax year 2018. I keep contacting my accountant but I do not receive a reply from him. I am very nervous because it's now time to start 2019 taxes and I still don't have my 2018 taxes completed. I need advice on what I can do?

Comment: Fire your accountant and hire someone else? What other advice are you looking for? Do you have copies of all of the records for 2018?

Comment: Join the club, my personal taxes from 2018 are still not filed.  Provided you do not owe taxes, you are fine.  My business taxes were not filed until late October.  If you like your accountant keep him.  Mine is fantastic and this is no big deal.

Comment: Go to his office??

Comment: @DStanley "Do you have copies of **all** of the records for 2018?"  Maybe not, if some information went directly to the accountant.

Comment: @PeteB. How fantastic can they be if they are running such a backlog?

Comment: @HartCO Clearly so fantastic that they have too many customers!

Comment: @Joe  You got it, they are super nice, and offer invaluable council.  We recommend them to a lot of people.  Anyone can do taxes, they are awesome.

Comment: I suppose as long as they are timely when it matters and don't leave you worrying then it's fine. I've encountered/heard about too many unorganized/lazy/overwhelmed CPA's out there that I am skeptical. Not responding to messages and failing to keep your clients updated on the status of their return is unacceptable to me, so OP's guy would be gone if it were me.

Answer (score 1):

A two prong approach is required:

- initiate a search for a new accountant
- continue to contact the old accountant for the data needed by the new accountant.

Accountants are seasonally busy (if not deceased), so timing can be key.